# Botched Migration: Table already deleted

Tags: django, django-south

I'm not sure what went wrong, but I have a migration to remove a model (database table). The table has been removed, but South does not think the migration has been applied, so when I migrate it tries to remove it, and fails, halting further migrations.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do to fix this kind of inconsistency is run the migration with `--fake`:

`./manage.py migrate app --fake`

From the [docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html):

> `--fake`: Records the migration sequence as having been applied, but doesn’t actually run it. Useful for Converting An App.